# Pegar valores de $request

Tags: php, get, symfony-2

Gostaria de pegar todos os valores de uma determinada key de um request.

Ex Request:

> nnmSoftware=7-Zip&idSoftware=1181&nmLocal=Empresa&idRede=1&nmSoftware=account-plugin-aim&idSoftware=1&nmLocal=Empresa&idRede=1,
>   referer: http://localhost/app_dev.php/relatorio/software/inventariados

Mas quando tento pegar com `$software = $request->get('idSoftware');` retorna apenas `idSoftware = 1`.

Como eu faria para pegar todos? `idSoftware = 1, 1181`

Comment: Que `$request` é esse? Não seria `$_REQUEST['key']`?

Comment: exatamente, gmsantos. Mas mesmo utilizando $_REQUEST['idSoftware'] ele tras apenas 1 idSoftware

Comment: Não tenho como testar no momento, mas acredito que pode adicionar para um array: array_push($array, $request->get('idSoftware'))

Comment: Tá usando algum framework?

Comment: Tente `$var = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

parse_str($var, $result); print_r($result); `

Comment: @LuisHenrique utilizando array_push retorna vazio.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, utilizao o symfony.

Comment: @BrunoMenezes repare na sua query, você chama `idSoftware` duas vezes! Por isso o valor é 1: nnmSoftware=7-Zip& **idSoftware=1181** &nmLocal=Empresa&idRede=1&nmSoftware=account-plugin-aim& **idSoftware=1** &nmLocal=Empresa&idRede=1. Fazer isso via GET não é possível, somente via POST.

Comment: @gmsantos isso mesmo. Eu preciso pegar esses dois valores. Em algumas situações terei 200 IdSoftwares

Comment: Estou sem tempo pra responder agora, mas basicamente você precisa que o metodo seja enviado via POST e tenha `[]` no nome do `input`: `<input name="idSoftware[]">`. Assim `idSoftware` será um array.

Comment: Concordo com você e sugiro a utilização de POST. No entanto, serializando o array antes de passar por get não resolveria o problema @gmsantos?

Comment: @gmsantos Perfeito. Muito obrigado, era exatamente isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na query, o campo `idSoftware` se repete duas vezes:

> nnmSoftware=7-Zip&**idSoftware=1181**&nmLocal=Empresa&idRede=1&nmSoftware=account-plugin-aim&**idSoftware=1**&nmLocal=Empresa&idRede=1

Ao fazer isso o GET reconhece somente o último `idSoftware` com valor `1`.

Para receber todas as ocorrências de `idSoftware` você precisa que o método seja enviado via POST e tenha `[]` no nome do *input*. Assim `idSoftware` será um array.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input name="idSoftware[]">
    <input name="idSoftware[]">
    <input name="idSoftware[]">
</form>
```

Resultado:

```
array(1) {
  ["idSoftware"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    int(118)
  }
}
```